# books for aspiring DBA

Tags: learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Must-read Books for DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213/must-read-books-for-dba)

What books do you recommend for the aspiring DBA?

Update: I'm particularly looking for sql-server and PostgreSQL books (though books geared towards other DB's might be helpful to keep in one place).