# Good video tutorials/series for learning Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am a better learner with visual content. Therefore I actively seek video tutorials when I start learning a subject. For oracle below links are my finds. I would like some additions to these.

- Oresoft youtube Oracle Server Concept
  http://www.youtube.com/user/TheOresoft#grid/user/8A9FE158DD9759AD
- Oracle DBA Justin
  http://www.youtube.com/user/jbleistein11#p/u
- Oresoft Oracle SQL
  http://www.youtube.com/user/TheOresoft#grid/user/EB058E78A206806C
- Oresoft Oracle PLSQL
  http://www.youtube.com/user/TheOresoft#grid/user/3245012E0631F7AE
- Oracle VTC
  http://www.vtc.com/products/oracle-10g-tutorials.htm

Comment: @jcolebrand I would like to learn what is difference between this question and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213/must-read-books-for-dba?

Comment: @Atilla Some slip through the net, but we really want [practical, answerable questions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) here rather than "shopping list" type questions. Your other contributions have been spot on ;)

Answer (score 2):

Search the [Oracle Learning Library / OBE (Oracle-By-Example)](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:2:0%3aFORCE_QUERY%3a:2,RIR,CIR%3aP2_SEARCH,P2_GROUP_ID%3aSQL,1000)