# Good book on databases for beginners

Tags: learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Must-read Books for DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213/must-read-books-for-dba)

I'm already reading a book on Introduction to SQL (RDMS). But that only teaches SQL and commands and I feel like my knowledge lacks in database management. Can you recommend me a good book to Database management which teaches about managing the databases instead of just using the queries to get something done?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which flavor of RDBMS you're working with.  Oracle database management is significantly different from SQL Server database management, for instance.

I answered a similar question recently [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/hints-to-train-yourself-as-a-oracle-dba/8971#8971), but one of the best (Oracle) DBA books that I've read is Darl Kuhn's [Pro Oracle Database Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430229705).  I used it as a textbook in graduate school, and it covers everything from install, config, backups, partitioning, etc, as well as common real-life problems and their solutions.

I wouldn't classify it as being for "beginners", but I had never had any database management before either, and I did ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are some generic books out there that may teach you general database design and such. If you want to get into the administration of it you will need to select a RDBMS to work with. The components of each RDBMS are different and require different methodologies for managing them.

If you want to get familar with database design (which I think and DBA should know) there is a self-paced and free online course that Stanford professors are offering on their own time. You can find that [here](http://db-class.org).

As I work with SQL Server I can only suggest books dealing with that RDBMS but a few I would suggest:
Buck Woody's [Administrator's Guide to SQL Server 2005](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321397975) (older version but still applies)
Thomas LaRock's [DBA Survivor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430227877)
(Multiple Authors) [Beginning SQL Server 2008 Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224134)
[Learning SQL Server in a Month of Lunches](http://manning.com/fritchey/) (this book is still in the process of completion but Manning publishing lets you get chapters as they are finished, then when it is done you get a complete copy of it)